# Which NP-Complete problem has the fastest known algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, np-complete

In terms of worst-case asymptotic runtime, which NP-complete problem has the fastest-known (exact) algorithm and what is the algorithm? Is there something known that is faster than $O(n^2*2^n)$?

Comment: What algorithm has running time $O(n^2 \cdot 2^n)$? EDIT: I assume you mean the Held–Karp algorithm for Traveling Salesman.

Comment: You can take a look at the answers to the question [Are there subexponential-time algorithms for NP-complete problems?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/are-there-subexponential-time-algorithms-for-np-complete-problems).

Comment: "Faster than $O(\_)$" does not make sense. You mean $\Theta$? Or is the question, "Is there an algorithm with a better proven upper runtime bound than $O(\_)$?"

Comment: The latter. It's valid point; there could be an algorithm A that's faster than B in practice but not with a tighter upper bound. I'm not sure why it doesn't make sense to say "faster than an upper bound" rather than "faster than a lower AND upper bound"...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Vertex Cover has an algorithm running in time $1.2738^k + nk$, and is thus faster than $2^n n^2$, even with $k=n$.  You can check out [Table of FPT races](http://fpt.wikidot.com/fpt-races) for a short list of FPT running times of different problems. Here, $n$ is the number of vertices and $k$ is the solution size.

Also, the question [Are there subexponential-time algorithms for NP-complete problems?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/are-there-subexponential-time-algorithms-for-np-complete-problems) addresses similar questions.

Comment: The questions asks for fastest known algorithms and the table you link to *does* have "faster" algorithms than the VC one (in particular subexponential ones), so it's probably not the best to cite.

Comment: See also this similar question and David Eppstein's answer [Best-case Running-time to solve an NP-Complete problem](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6418/best-case-running-time-to-solve-an-np-complete-problem) on mathoverflow.

Comment: @Raphael Yes, for instance Minimum Fill-In has an algorithm which for every $\epsilon > 0$, runs in $O( (1+\epsilon)^k + \text{poly}(n))$ time.