# Why doesn't subset sum solution violate Exponential Time Hypothesis?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete

The quickest algorithm for solving subset sum currently is $2^{n/2}$ (via Wiki).  Why doesn't this violate the Exponential Time Hypothesis which states that “there is no family of algorithms that can solve 3-SAT in $2^{o(n)}$ time.”

Couldn't a 3-SAT problem be translated to a subset sum problem in polynomial time and then solved in $2^{n/2}$ time.  What am I missing here?

Comment: n goes up by a very big factor when you reduce 3-SAT to subset sum

Comment: Well it also says that any related NP-complete problem (i.e. subset sum) cannot be solved in subexponential time.  Isn't 2^(n/2) subexponential?

Comment: Isn't it $2^{poly(n)}$, which is exponential?

Comment: [Exponential](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/are-there-subexponential-time-algorithms-for-np-complete-problems) - I am sure that this explanation is trustworthy.

Comment: n/2 is not o (n). It is O (n). Little-o versus Big-O. $2^{n/2}$ is not subexponential. It is larger than $1.4^n$.

Answer (score 3):

Given a 3SAT problem of size $n$, you can convert that to a subset sum problem of size $n^2$ (roughly).  Now you can apply the algorithm for subset sum to solve the subset sum in time $2^{n^2/2}$ (roughly).  Remember, the running time depends on the size (length) of the input, and here the size of the input will be $n^2$, yielding the $2^{n^2/2}$ figure.

That will give you an algorithm for solving a 3SAT problem of size $n$ in $2^{n^2/2}$ time (roughly).  But that's much worse than the naive algorithm, which takes $2^n$ time: $2^n$ is much smaller than $2^{n^2/2}$.  So this reduction does not contradict the exponential time hypothesis: it doesn't give you a way to solve 3SAT faster than $2^n$ time.

Comment: Ok. I buy that - transformation from 3SAT to SUBSET SUM yields n^2 and the result would be 2^(n^2/2).  But the Exponential Time Hypothesis also says that any NP-complete problem cannot be solved in subexponential time.  I guess 2^N/2 is not considered subexponential?

Comment: @CShreve, the ETH doesn't say that.  Read it again.  $2^{n/2}$ time is not subexponential.  ETH talks about SAT, not all NP-complete problems, and it talks about $2^{o(n)}$, and $n/2$ is not $o(n)$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9813/755.  Please don't use the comments to ask follow-up questions or for extended discussion.

Comment: @D.W. So is there a $poly(2^{\sqrt n})$ time algorithm for subset sum? It wont violate ETH right?