# Strongly NP-hard problems and Dynamic Programming

Tags: np-complete, dynamic-programming, np-hard

Dynamic Programming seems to result in good performance algorithms for [Weakly NP-hard Problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_NP-completeness). Two examples are [Subset Sum Problem](http://crystal.uta.edu/~gdas/Courses/Courses/Spring2011/6311SubsetSum.pdf) and [0-1 Knapsack Problem](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/fall11/rec/rec21_knapsack.pdf), both problems are solvable in **pseudo-polynomial** time using Dynamic Programming. It turns out this is a pretty good result in most cases.

On the other hand, [Strongly NP-hard Problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_NP-completeness) seem to be essentially exponential even by using Dynamic Programming. For example, the [Multiple 0-1 Knapsack Problem](http://www.or.deis.unibo.it/kp/Chapter6.pdf) (page 11).

Is this a true claim if I generalize my observations and state *Dynamic Programming is good for Weakly NP-hard Problems but it is not suitable for Strongly NP-hard Problems*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're generalizing too much from a small sample size.  There is no guarantee that all weakly NP-complete problems can be solved using dynamic programming; I'd expect probably there are some that dynamic programming isn't much good for.

And, there is no guarantee that a strongly NP-hard problem will take exponential time to solve.  [There are NP-complete problems that can be solved faster than exponential time](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9813/755).  (See also the [exponential time hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis).)

Dynamic programming is just one algorithmic technique among many.  There's nothing magical about it, and it's not a be-all and end-all.  There are other algorithmic methods other than dynamic programming.

Comment: If multiple knapsack is SNP-hard, then under assumption of ETH correctness, it can't be solved in subexponential time. But I don't know if multiple knapsack is SNP-hard.