# NP-completeness of a problem with pretty fast algorithm

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete, np

Supposing if a problem with $n$ non-deterministic bits is in $O(2^{\alpha n})$ time at every $\alpha\in(0,1)$ then is there evidence that problem can or cannot be $\mathsf{NP}$-complete?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there subexponential-time algorithms for NP-complete problems?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/are-there-subexponential-time-algorithms-for-np-complete-problems)

Comment: Don't think so. Here non-determinism is given to be $n$ and though input bits is $n$ non-deterministic bits is $n^\gamma$ at a $\gamma\in(0,1)$ with is fixed and thus the limit of the exponent in terms of non-deterministic bits is $\alpha n$ at any $\alpha>0$ here and there $\alpha=\Omega(1)$ holds (for example with clique reduction non-determinism is $\sqrt{n}$). Thus it appears $\mathsf{ETH}$ is violated if it were $\mathsf{NP}$ complete.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such problems can be NP-complete.

Consider classical NP-complete graph problems like clique.

Clique has an $O(2^n)$ time algorithm, where $n$ is the number of vertices. However the input for clique is the adjacency matrix of the graph, which has $n^2$ bits. Therefore when the size of input is measured in bits, clique has an $O(2^\sqrt{n})$ time algorithm, which is $O(2^{\alpha n})$ for any positive $\alpha$.