# Is GNFS quasi-polynomial-time?

Tags: time-complexity, number-theory, factoring

Wikipedia states that the time complexity of the [General Number Field Sieve (GNFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) is
$$\exp\left( \left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{64}{9}} + o(1)\right)(\log N)^{\frac{1}{3}}(\log \log N)^{\frac{2}{3}}\right),$$
where $N$ is the number to be factored.

The same site also mentions that [quasi-polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Quasi-polynomial_time) is
$$\mbox{QP} = \bigcup_{c \in \mathbb{N}} \mbox{DTIME} \left(2^{\log^c n}\right),$$
where $n$ is the length of the input, in other words, $n=\log N$.

Now my question is whether GNFS is quasi-polynomial-time. It appears not, because of the existence of the $(\log N)^{1/3}$ exponent.

How about [sub-exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Sub-exponential_time)? Wikipedia says
$$\text{SUBEXP}=\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} \text{DTIME}\left(2^{n^\varepsilon}\right).$$
I think the answer is still negative, because $\varepsilon=1/3$ in this case and it can’t be smaller as the intersection requires.

So the running time is exponential. Am I right?

**Update**

In the table of contents of the book *Prime Numbers: A Computational Perspective*, NFS and Quadratic Sieve (QS) are both listed in Chapter 6 Subexponential Factoring Algorithms.

Comment: I encourage you to edit your post to avoid using the same variable $n$ for two different things.

Answer (score 2):

Using the same variable $n$ to mean two different things in two places is confusing.  In the context of your question, I think it is better to describe the running time of GNFS as $$\exp\left( (c+o(1)) \, n^{\frac{1}{3}}(\log n)^{\frac{2}{3}}\right),$$
where $n$ is the number of bits in the number being factored, and $c$ is a constant.

With this formulation, it is clear that it is not in QP ($n^{1/3}$ is not in $O(\log^c n)$ for any $c$), and not in SUBEXP ($n^{1/3}$ is not in $O(n^{\varepsilon})$ when $0<\varepsilon<1/3$).  Yet as Wikipedia explains, there are multiple different definitions of sub-exponential; by some of them, GNFS runs in sub-exponential time, and by others, it does not.  See also [Are there subexponential-time algorithms for NP-complete problems?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9813/755).